# $\sqrt x$ continuity using $\epsilon-\delta$ definition

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, continuity, epsilon-delta

Let $x_{0}\in [0,+\infty)$, $\epsilon>0$

Suppose we have: $|x-x_{0}|<\delta$ where $\delta>0$

$|f(x)-f(x_{0})|=|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt x_{0}|\le\sqrt{x}+\sqrt x_{0}$

$|x-x_{0}|<\delta\implies x<\delta+x_{0}\implies \sqrt{x}<\sqrt{\delta+x_{0}}\le\sqrt{\delta}+\sqrt{x_{0}}$

So if we want to make $\sqrt{\delta}+2\sqrt x_0\le\epsilon$, we get $\delta\le (\epsilon-2\sqrt x_{0})^2$, but what if $x_{0}=\epsilon$ ?

Comment: You cannot use $|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{x_0}| \leq \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x_0}$ to show what you want as the right hand side does not go to zero as $x\to x_0$. It's too weak an inequality. Try to use  $|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x_0}| \leq \frac{|x-x_0|}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x_0}}$ instead

Comment: So generally, when proving continuity, if the right-hand side is a function $f(x)$, we want limit $f(x)$ as $x$ tends to $x_{0}$ to be $0$? @Winther

Comment: Yes. Continuity is the statement that if $x\to a$ then $f(x)\to f(a)$, or rewritten slightly: if $|x-a|\to 0$ then $|f(x) - f(a)| \to 0$. Thus if you want to show this then you cannot use the given inequality as it's too weak to show what you want.